# WebStorm disable JS debugger content highlight

Tags: css, webstorm, javascript-debugger

Title may be confusing because I don't know how to explain that in words. When we use JavaScript debugger in WebStorm and edit and html file, it colorizes the block when the cursor on it.

It is really confuses me specially when I change something about the design. Is there any way to turn of this feature completely. I'm digging the app, searching at google but nothing found yet

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try disabling **Highlight current element in browser on caret change** checkbox in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit**

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/live-editing.html